# Jboss Datagrid server leveldb cache lock - Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: datagrid, jboss, infinispan, leveldb

I am running 2 instances of Jboss Datagrid server in RHEL in distributed mode. I am using leveldb cache store as my level 2 cache. Both of these instance should use the same leveldb cache store path and should write the key/value to this path.

/shared/usr/local/leveldb.

here is my configuration

(There is a softlink created inside the data directory so that the leveldb path is pointed to the same shared directory in both servers).

I am getting the following error on the second instance (first instance is comping up without any issues). I am using shared="true" in the configuration which should allow both datagrid servers to access the same cache store.

2016-12-05 13:15:19,077 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.datagrid-infinispan.clustered.mycache: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.datagrid-infinispan.clustered.mycache: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start() on object of type PersistenceManagerImpl
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:172)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:864)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:633)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:622)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:547)
        at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:238)
        at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:877)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:637)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:587)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:452)
        at org.infinispan.manager.impl.AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.java:133)
        at org.infinispan.server.infinispan.SecurityActions$5.run(SecurityActions.java:130)
        at org.infinispan.server.infinispan.SecurityActions$5.run(SecurityActions.java:127)
        at org.infinispan.security.Security.doPrivileged(Security.java:76)
        at org.infinispan.server.infinispan.SecurityActions.doPrivileged(SecurityActions.java:63)
        at org.infinispan.server.infinispan.SecurityActions.startCache(SecurityActions.java:135)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheService.start(CacheService.java:86)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to start cache loaders
        at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Unable to open database
        at org.infinispan.persistence.leveldb.LevelDBStore.start(LevelDBStore.java:108)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:141)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB$DBException: IO error: lock /shared/usr/local/leveldb/data/mycache/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.checkStatus(NativeDB.java:200)
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.open(NativeDB.java:218)
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory.open(JniDBFactory.java:168)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.leveldb.LevelDBStore.openDatabase(LevelDBStore.java:153)
        at org.infinispan.persistence.leveldb.LevelDBStore.start(LevelDBStore.java:104)
        ... 27 more

Comment: Only one process can access leveldb at a time

Comment: So in distributed mode how can two nodes access the data in leveldb? In other words how can I share the data in leveldb store across multiple data grid servers?

Comment: you have to write simple wrapper  server around leveldb and use that for access instead of accessing directly

Comment: I've written a small daemon in ruby that can achieve multi-process access to LevelDB: https://github.com/dennisvink/leveldb-curator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LevelDB cache store cannot be shared, because LevelDB itself is not meant to be shared. I've created an issue to ensure that such mistakes can be prevented during configuration validation: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7286